Find most occuring value in 2-d array
I have data like this . I want to know which is most occuring value in this whole 2-d matrix
which is T-SPA  and I also want know from which ac_id it is coming ?
What is best way to this .

Need output like

adding as text
ac_id   v1_val  v2_val  v3_val
1   T-PA        SpA 
23  T-SPA               T-SPA
24  T-SPA   T-SPA       T-S.P.A


What should be the output? ac_id = [23, 24]?

Yes along with value which is T-SPA

Along with value? Please [edit] your question and put there expected output. Also, please put the input 2-d matrix as text (so we can copy-paste it).

Added as mentioned . Please let me know IF i need to do anything

I'm assuming you have this dataframe:
   ac_id v1_val v2_val   v3_val
0      1   T-PA    SpA      NaN
1     23  T-SPA    NaN    T-SPA
2     24  T-SPA  T-SPA  T-S.P.A

Then to find most occuring value you can do e.g.:
out = df.set_index("ac_id").stack().value_counts()
print(out)

Prints:
T-SPA      4
T-PA       1
SpA        1
T-S.P.A    1
Name: count, dtype: int64

print(out.index[0])

Prints:
T-SPA

to find the ac_id:
ac_ids = df.loc[df.loc[:, "v1_val":].eq(out.index[0]).any(axis=1), "ac_id"]
print(ac_ids)

Prints:
1    23
2    24
Name: ac_id, dtype: int64

